# How can I configure CMake generated Eclipse project's Build Command and Project Paths?

Tags: cmake, eclipse-cdt

Our project uses CMake to configure our code. We use Ninja along with a distributed build system. A number of people on our team use Eclipse CDT. We run CMake with the "Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja" generator and the result is generally pretty good.

The issues is that any time a CMake file is changed and you ask Eclipse to build the code it regenerate the eclipse project file overwriting any manual changes you've made to the project.

For example the default build command that it provides the eclipse project is `/usr/bin/ninja` when in fact I want to take advantage of our distributed build system and set the build command to `/usr/bin/ninja -j16`. It would be nice if I could have the project file that CMake generates automatically include this setting change.

The other setting I am most interested in preserving is the `C/C++ Project Paths->Source`. As a general rule we place our CMake build directory as a sibling to the main project directory i.e. `./project` `./build`. We want to include some files in the build directory in the Eclipse index to make code completion and other tools work better. The default project doesn't include the build directory in source path and thus it does not get indexed.

Is there some way to remedy these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to build command issue.

When you run cmake to generate the eclipse project include the additional argument:`-DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_NINJA_ARGUMENTS=-j100`. I haven't confirmed but I believe a similar command is required for eclipse make projects `-DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j100`.

Unfortunately this feature is poorly documented and I have not found a solution to my other issue.